# ¿Como puedo hacer que los "Archivo.txt " tan solo el nombre del archivo lo pueda copiar, sin necesidad de escribir el .txt?

Tags: bash

Estoy realizando un Script Bash, **lo que quiero saber si hay forma para copiar un archivo.** Solo el nombre del archivo **sin la necesidad de llegar de escribir  con el** `.txt` Estoy usando **termux.**

**~ Archivo.txt --   Archivo1.txt**

**~**

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo
echo -ne "Ingrese el nombre de PlayLista: "; read nombre
#--> read nombre <---  hay Tengo de poner el nombre del "Archivo.txt" con .txt , para que se me pueda copear el archivo y si no pongo el ".txt" me sale error. 
#tan solo el nombre , sin la necesidad de escribir con el .text
cp $nombre /sdcard/downloads
```

Comment: Si se trata de copiar (por lo de `cp` en el comando), nótese que el tabulador es tu aliado: si empiezas a escribir un nombre de archivo y aprietas en el tabulador, te lo completa

Comment: Estoy haciendo un script y dentro del script ,  dentro de del script , Deceo copear archivo sin poner  ```.txt```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes concatenar el .txt dentro del script:

```
cp $nombre.txt /sdcard/downloads
```

Si quieres que se copie cualquier archivo sin importar su extensión:

```
cp $nombre.* /sdcard/downloads
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Por ser la persona tan amable! *-*